# Is it necessary to make the exact number of turns in each arm of the armature of a motor

Tags: motor

When making a motor is it necessary to make the exact same number of turns on each arm of the armature,let's say it should be 400 turns on each arm, would a difference of 2 to 5 turns extra on one arm change anything?

Comment: Other than causing an imbalance of torque?

Comment: and other than cause bearing vibration, everything has a tolerance including core permeability errors from fabrication faults in silicate laminate insulation, or contact brush resistance variation, so a tolerance budget is necessary. and dynamic mass balance is just as important. **The bigger the armature the more critical the % mismatch.**

Comment: The effect of 2 to 5 turns extra depends on the number of turns, and the existing inbalance.

Comment: If the motor was wound perfectly, would driving an eccentric load affect anything?

Comment: That will cause imbalance while armature is rotating. That is why dummy coils are put. These are coils that have same weight distribution as other coils but are electrically insulated from armature circuit. If the number of slots on rotor and number of poles on stator are predetermined then you may not always have a choice but to put in dummy coils.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is necessary because you don't want the weight of each arm to be unbalanced, depending on the required number of turns on each arm, adding 2-5 more turns wont really hut any body, for example, if the number of turns are 400 on each arm, then it is safe to have a difference of 2-5 turns.